# How do struct{} and struct{}{} work in Go?

Tags: go, struct, syntax

I am wondering what does "struct{}" and "struct{}{}" mean in Go? An example is as follows:

```
array[index] = struct{}{}
```

or

```
make(map[type]struct{})
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330330/using-maps-as-sets-by-using-structs-in-go-is-the-performance-the-reason

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`struct` is a [keyword](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords) in Go. It is used to define [struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), which is a sequence of named elements.

For example:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

The `struct{}` is a `struct` type with zero elements. It is often used when no information is to be stored. It has the benefit of being 0-sized, so usually no memory is required to store a value of type `struct{}`.

`struct{}{}` on the other hand is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), it constructs a value of type `struct{}`. A composite literal constructs values for types such as structs, arrays, maps and slices. Its syntax is the type followed by the elements in braces. Since the "empty" struct (`struct{}`) has no fields, the elements list is also empty:

```
 struct{}  {}
|  ^     | ^
  type     empty element list
```

As an example let's create a "set" in Go. Go does not have a builtin set data structure, but it has a builtin map. We can use a map as a set, as a map can only have at most one entry with a given key. And since we want to only store keys (elements) in the map, we may choose the map value type to be `struct{}`.

A map with `string` elements:

```
var set map[string]struct{}
// Initialize the set
set = make(map[string]struct{})

// Add some values to the set:
set["red"] = struct{}{}
set["blue"] = struct{}{}

// Check if a value is in the map:
_, ok := set["red"]
fmt.Println("Is red in the map?", ok)
_, ok = set["green"]
fmt.Println("Is green in the map?", ok)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zvQU9E6m6J)):

```
Is red in the map? true
Is green in the map? false
```

Note that however it may be more convenient to use `bool` as the value type when creating a set out of a map, as the syntax to check if an element is in it is simpler. For details, see [How can I create an array that contains unique strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207197/how-can-i-create-an-array-that-contains-unique-strings/33207265#33207265).

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out by izca:

Struct is a go keyword for defining struct types which are just user defined types composed of variables of whatever arbitrary type you decide.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

Structs can also be empty with Zero elements.
However Struct{}{} has a different meaning. This is a composite struct literal. It inline defines a struct type and defines an struct and assigns no property.

```
emptyStruct := Struct{} // This is an illegal operation
// you define an inline struct literal with no types
// the same is true for the following

car := struct{
          Speed  int
          Weight float
       }
// you define a struct be do now create an instance and assign it to car
// the following however is completely valid

car2 := struct{
          Speed  int
          Weight float
       }{6, 7.1}

//car2 now has a Speed of 6 and Weight of 7.1
```

This line here just creates a map of empty struct literals which is perfectly legal.

```
make(map[type]struct{})
```

It is the same as

```
make(map[type]struct{
        x int
        y int
     })
```