# What does the double curly brace mean in []interface{}{}

Tags: go

Please note this is double curly braces in this format{}{}, and not nested curly braces {{}}.  I am also unsure if this is an empty interface issue, a slice issue or a struct issue. I am guessing it is a combination of at least two of these.

I am learning Golang and I have reached empty interfaces. I see I need to declare a slice of empty interfaces as

```
[]interface{}{}
```

or for instance

```
[]interface{}{"aa","bb"}
```

I don't just want to blindly start using it. Whereas I understand the idea of empty interfaces, and that an interface contains two portions of data, the value and the type, I just don't understand the {}{} structure? I learned that slices are created with make() or for instance
    []int{}

What is the extra {} for when using empty interfaces?

Thank you

I have googled it, and went through my tutorials. I also compared it to what I know about structs as I suspect a interface is a struct. My attempts to google golang interfaces yields mainly normal interfaces, with which I have no problem.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals and a related question with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122905/how-do-struct-and-struct-work-in-go

Comment: This is a good question, not sure why so many dislike for it.

Comment: Upvote, I had the very same doubt. Also don't understand the downvotes...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[]interface{}` is the type: a slice `[]` of empty interface `interface{}` (which is actually an anonymous inline type declaration). The second set of braces instantiates an instance of that type, so `[]interface{}{}` is an empty slice of empty interface, `[]interface{}{"aa","bb"}` is a slice of empty interface with two items. That could also be `[]string{"aa","bb"}`, a slice of string with two items, which is the same thing with a different type (`string` in place of `interface{}`).

You could also have a non-empty interface, like `[]interface{SomeFunc()}{}` being an empty slice of `interface{SomeFunc()}`, a non-empty anonymous interface type. Or you could do it with an anonymous struct type, like `[]struct{Foo string}{{"bar"},{"baz"}}`. Here there's even more braces - the first pair around the type definition body, the second pair around the slice literal, and within that, one pair each around two struct literals.

Comment: I came looking for the answer about your last example, even though it is not in the question. Thank you for your thoroughness :)

Answer (score 8):

`interface{}` is the empty interface type

`[]interface{}` is a slice of type empty interface

`interface{}{}` is an empty interface type composite literal

`[]interface{}{}` is a slice of type empty interface composite literals

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)
>
> [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)
>
> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

---

Take the Go Tour: [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)