# Is it possible to have interface composite literals in Go?

Tags: go, interface, composite-literals

I just want to confirm if my understanding is correct about `interface{}{}`

Does `interface{}{}` mean a composite literal of interface type?

So, if I wanted to pass a composite type, lets say `[]byte` as a `interface{}`, I should assign it to a variable of type `interface{}{}` and pass in that variable, whereas if I wanted to pass a non composite type, such as a `int` as a `interface{}`, I should assign it to a variable of type `interface{}` and pass in that variable.

Is my understanding correct on this?

Comment: both scenarios, you can use variable with type interface{}.

Comment: Related: [What does the double curly brace mean in `[]interface{}{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149795/what-does-the-double-curly-brace-mean-in-interface?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

`interface{}{}` is invalid syntax.

It is not an empty interface composite literal — there's no such thing. The following don't compile:

```
var a interface{}{} = "foo" // not a type
b := interface{}{}          // not a value
```

From the specs [Composite Literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> Composite literals construct values for **structs, arrays, slices, and maps** and create a new value each time they are evaluated.

The valid syntax is `interface{}`, which is the empty interface, i.e. an interface with no name and empty method set.

If you compare it to a named interface, you will see that the extra set of curly braces at the end makes no sense:

```
type Fooer interface {
    Foo() error
}{} // ???
```

You can instantiate an empty `interface{}` by converting `nil`:

```
a := (interface{})(nil)
```

Or you can declare a var of unnamed interface type:

```
type A struct {}

func (a A) Foo() string {
    return "foo"
}

var a interface{ Foo() string } = A{}
```

---

To answer your question:

> So, if I wanted to pass a composite type [...]

you can assign any value to a variable of type `interface{}`, that's about it. Whether the value is composite or not is irrelevant because all types satisfy the empty interface:

```
var a interface{} = []byte{0x01, 0x02}
var b interface{} = "string_literal"
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/w-l1dU-6Hb5

Comment: So what's the difference between `someVar := make(map[string]interface{})` and `someVar := map[string]interface{}{}` ?

Comment: @NimaKapoor the latter is a composite literal of type `map[string]interface{}`. The final `{}` constructs the map.

Comment: OK, if the latter is a composite literal of type `map[string]interface{}`, then what is the former?

Comment: @NimaKapoor the former is a type, passed to the [`make`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#make) function, as you can see from its signature `func make(t Type, size ...IntegerType) Type`, that takes a type. In both cases `map[string]interface{}` is a type. In the former case the value is initialized with the built-in `make` function, in the latter case it is initialized with a composite literal.

Answer (score 0):

1. `interface{}` type of empty interface.
2. you assign `[]byte` or `int` to any empty variable of empty interface (`interface{}` type) or you can pass it directly to function that exepts interface values.

Comment: So what's the difference between 

`someVar := make(map[string]interface{})`

and

`someVar := map[string]interface{}{}`

Comment: there is no difference in this constuctions. both are maps with string as key and interfaces{} as value with a name `someVar`. What you might be missing is `v := map[string]int{}` this is the syntax of declaring a map (usually with a value, but in its example without , hence extra confusing `{}`).

Answer (score 0):

The empty interface `interface{}` essentially says "I don't care". Anything can be passed as an empty interface. So for your examples they all could be stored as the empty interface.

Possibly a more interesting question is why you want to avoid types in the first place, and what you're trying to achieve. But for the purposes of using interface{} you can pass anything to it, even a "nil".