# What is {} in Golang?

Tags: go, struct

I came across this in lecture notes:

```
setCollection := map[string]struct{}{
        "uniqElement1": {},
        "uniqElement2": {},
        "uniqElement3": {},
}
```

As I understand, {} here represents the empty struct, but I never saw this before. Does this always mean an empty struct? Also, when can we use this notation? This code doesn't work:

```
setCollection["newElem"] = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` are syntax requirement of [composite literal values](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Your first example uses a composite literal to create a map value, and **inside** that literal it uses other struct literals for the key values of the map. And the Spec allows to omit the inner type in the inner literal:

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type `T`, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of `T`. Similarly, elements or keys that are addresses of composite literals may elide the `&T` when the element or key type is `*T`.

Your second example tries to use `{}` not in a composite literal, and the compiler does not know what type you want to use. So it's a compile time error. You have to be explicit in the second example:

```
setCollection["newElem"] = struct{}{}
```

Where `struct{}` is the type, and `struct{}{}` is a composite literal value (of type `struct{}`).

See related: [How do struct{} and struct{}{} work in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122905/how-do-struct-and-struct-work-in-go/45123114#45123114)